# Displaying crossover only in d3.js Slankey (Dynamic, Interactive)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, sankey-diagram

I am aiming to create a d3.js visualisation dashboard that shows the flow of mutual connections based on a selection for 'a', that provides a statistic for 'b', shaped like a Sankey/Parallel Set. For instance, if 'a' is the user selection, where they select 3 of 11 characteristics of people, then b would be a count of how many people in our sample have all three characteristics.

Think of this like a Sankey/Parallel Set diagram where on the left we see the characteristics (Happy, Loyal, Calm), flowing into one container (200/1000 (with characteristics selected/total population).

I am wondering if anyone knows a pre-established way to JUST displays the crossover that the user defines in a navbar pre-selection.

Thanks.

Data:

[![It's a boolean array, with totals. It's like a permutations and combinations spreadsheet
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3vJB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3vJB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you're looking to make a crossover slankey like me, I recommend modelling here:

http://sankeymatic.com/build/

Once you get into it, it's very easy to label what the final node should be, and encourage output to flow to that node.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this for a variety of sankey's,

https://observablehq.com/search?query=sankey

Comment: Thank you for responding, I will check this out.

Do you have an idea as to how I might be able to flow to one crossover node?

Comment: do you have a sample data? if so, post it a few rows of 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help :)



I've attached to main Q